# call a vb.net class function from javascript

Tags: .net, javascript

I want to make a call to a function of vb.net class from javascript. I mean I would call something which doesnot have extention as .aspx but rather .vb only. Is is possible? how?

Thanks and regards,
Tanmay.

Answer (score 3):

If you add

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
```

To your function signature then you can use PageMethods to call that function from JavaScript

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>_
Public Shared Function DisplayDate()
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now()
End Function
```

So now add a ScriptManager to your page and in the ScriptManager do this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ShowDate()
{
    PageMethods.DisplayDate();
}
```